# Cannot resolve symbol host in GenericHostBuilder .netcore 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to use DI in my simple console application.
when I try to use IHostBuilder in my class I get an error: 'Can not resolve symbol Host'.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args)
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
}
```

Comment: Host should be a public class in Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting. Are you sure the reference points to a DI lib for the correct framework .netcore 5 ?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and I fixed it by removing some packages except `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`. It works and afterwards I added the other packages again.